# What type should I give meals in this case?

Tags: typescript, redux, types, react-redux

[image]

[image]

Hello, I neeed help with this, I don't know what type I should give my props which I want to pass to a redux slice.

I'm getting the error "argument of type 'Meal[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Meal'.
Type 'Meal[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Meal': _id, _createdAt, _updatedAt, _ref, and 7 more.ts(2345)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=Type import from next-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
import type { NextPage, GetServerSideProps } from "next";
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=Componenets imports--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
import { Header } from "../components/header/header";
import { Revolver } from "../components/revolver/revolver";
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-utilties fetches-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
import { fetchMeals } from "../util/fetchMeals";
import { fetchCategories } from "../util/fetchCategories";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addMeals } from "../redux/mealsSlice";
import { addCategories } from "../redux/categoriesSlice";

// import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
// import { selectBasketItems } from "../redux/basketSlice";
// import { selectMealsItemsmeals } from "../redux/mealsSlice";

interface Props {
  categories: Category[];
  meals: Meal[];
}
const Home: NextPage<Props> = ({ categories, meals }: Props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch(addMeals(meals));
  useEffect(() => {
    // addAllMeals();
    // addAllCategories();
    // console.log("loading meals");
  }, []);

  // const addAllCategories = () => {
  //   dispatch(addCategories(categories));
  // };
  // const addAllMeals = () => {};

  return (
    <>`enter code here`
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Header />
      <Revolver />
    </>
  );
};
export default Home;

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- Backend Code=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-//
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async () => {
  const categories = await fetchCategories();
  const meals = await fetchMeals();
  return {
    props: {
      categories,
      meals,
    },
  };
};
```

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- This the slice I want to pass meals into

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { RootState } from "./store";

// Define a type for the slice state
interface mealsState {
  meals: Meal[];
}

// Define the initial state using that type
const initialState: mealsState = {
  meals: [],
};

export const mealsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "mealsItems",
  // `createSlice` will infer the state type from the `initialState` argument
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addMeals: (state: mealsState, action: PayloadAction<Meal>) => {
      state.meals = [...state.meals, action.payload];
    },
  },
});

//-=-==-export the reducers(setters)-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=//
export const { addMeals } = mealsSlice.actions;
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- Other code such as selectors can use the imported `RootState` type

export const selectMealsItemsmeals = (state: RootState) =>
  state.mealsItems.meals;

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-to be explained--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-//
// export const selectMealsItemsmealsWithId = (state: RootState, id: string) =>
//   state.MealsItems.meals.filter((item: Meal) => item._id === id);
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=select totlal in the MealsItems-=-=-=-=-=///|||||||||||||||
// export const selectMealsItemsTotal = (state: RootState) => {
//   state.MealsItems.meals.reduce(
//     (total: number, item: Meal) => (total += item.price),
//     0
//   );
// };

export default mealsSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 2):

Change line 20 to:

```
action: PayloadAction<Meal[]>
```

Comment: I  tired everything here and It did not work, I know the problems lays right here.